# How do other apps keep service running permanently?

Tags: android, android-service

This is similar to another question I asked where I was wondering how other apps like drupe dialer keep their service running forever when it is not in foreground. Because I've used job services, alarm manager, START_STICKY and everything else to try to keep my service alive but it always gets stopped by the OS.

Comment: *keep their service running forever when it is not in foreground* that is literally impossible

Comment: What device are you testing on?

Comment: I'm testing on a Samsung galaxy s6

Answer (score 0):

You can run the service as "Foreground" and it will be not candidate to be killed by the system under low memory conditions. The gotcha is that you will need to show that behavior to the user with a notification. This is the way that music players uses to go background and alive when you start another apps.

[Foreground Services](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html?hl=en-419#Foreground)

Answer (score 0):

The app you mentioned (Drupe Dialer) is a Dialer. It might be listening to broadcasts and turning the service up every time by checking whether its up.

To answer your question, you need to keep the service started as START_STICKY to make it restart after the OS kills it. But AlarmManager does not work at device sleep states, and doze will stop it from running in the background nevertheless.

The real question is; WHY you want to keep it running? That might answer your question on HOW you want to do that.

- If its a communication type app, you will need to use something like
  GCM.
- If its running background work based on some event, you might
  want to start the service inside the BroadcastReceiver.
- etc.

it depends on what app you're writing.

Comment: *To answer your question, you need to keep the service started as START_STICKY to make it restart after the OS kills it* that does not answer his question. Also doze does not "kill" apps

Comment: I know you can use broadcasts like connectivity change to check. But is there anything else I can do? Or does anyone know how specific apps keep their services alive permanently when they are in background and not in foreground

Comment: Also I wanna keep it running because I have a view on the window manager that I want the user to have access to whenever